# Codeigniter load views with ajax and url control

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, partial-views

I have a little trouble loading partial views by ajax. I used this schema:

config/constants.php

```
define('IS_AJAX', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest');
```

then each controller function, which need to be loaded by ajax contains:

```
  if(IS_AJAX){
    //action when AJAX request
    $this->load->view("partial_view", $data);
  }else{
    //action when user open page directly in browser
    $this->load->view('full_view',$data);
  }
```

for e.g. when I'm on home page (`http://example.com`) and i want to use Example controller  and Edit action.

Now, if IS_AJAX is true my content loaded correctly, but url in browser is still the same `http://example.com`.

else if IS_AJAX is false there is no problem. I've got url `http://example.com/example/edit/params`

How to change url for the AJAX requests to look like a standard CI url ?

P.S I don't want to use hash if it's not needed :/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page/3354511#3354511

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry.. 
you can use this to change URL without load the page :

```
history.pushState({},null,'http://example-new-url.com');
```

Comment: So, how it's done here: http://www.josephaavoue.com ?
Go to page Archives or Contact. It's XMLHttpRequest and link not conatins hash :(

Comment: I found one that may be will help you :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page